# Change UILabel text storyboard programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, storyboard, uilabel

I would like to change `UILabel` on press the `UIButton`. I need to load screen before, but how can I do it in storyboard? Now code is something like this:

[image]

Code here (.h file):

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *idLabel; // label to change
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *addingButton; // clickOnButton

@end
```

And method (.m file):

```
- (IBAction)addingHasTaped:(id)sender {
    NetworkConnection *request = [[NetworkConnection alloc]init];
    [request getDataFromServer];
    self.idLabel.text = @"hi!"; 
}
```

I use storyboard and I drag and drop `UILabel` and `UIButton` to code. But this method doesn't change `UILabel`.

What is wrong?

Comment: Check UILabel is connected with UILabel IBOutlet.

Comment: Check - (IBAction)addingHasTaped:(id)sender is connected as button action.

Comment: Do you want to change the same lable in the current viewController or another lable in another viewCOntroller?

Comment: Add more detail to the question so that the answer can be explained accordingly...

Comment: I would like to change it in one view controller.

Comment: @vikichocolate check whether your IBAction is called by keeping breakpoint on that?

Comment: Kathiravan G, sorry but I don't understand you exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should  Synthesis Property of your Label  And Also Check if you are getting Call in your Method .

Comment: sorry, I don't understand you exactly